# not able to run wildfly 10.1.0 server in windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly-10

I am trying to re-install wildfly server after deleting it by mistake. This is my college assignment and I dont have any idea about wildfly. I have put the folder in my C drive and opening the file from bin directory. 
At first it was running perfectly but after re installing its giving following error

```
    Calling "C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

===============================================================================

20:06:54,951 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
20:06:55,629 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
20:06:55,813 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
20:06:58,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:06:58,077 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
20:06:58,092 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
20:06:58,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:06:58,170 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
20:06:58,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
20:06:58,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:06:58,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:06:58,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
20:06:58,248 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
20:06:58,280 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
20:06:58,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
20:06:58,327 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
20:06:58,358 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
20:06:58,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
20:06:58,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:06:58,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:06:58,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:06:58,608 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
20:06:58,655 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
20:06:58,670 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
20:06:58,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
20:06:58,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
20:06:58,795 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
20:06:58,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:06:59,108 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
20:06:59,139 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
20:06:59,249 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990
        at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:273)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

20:06:59,358 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
20:06:59,389 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,389 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,405 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,389 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,405 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,405 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
20:06:59,592 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
20:06:59,967 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6)
20:06:59,983 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
20:06:59,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.serverManagement.controller.management.http: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990

20:07:00,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0063: Http management interface is not enabled
20:07:00,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0054: Admin console is not enabled
20:07:00,124 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 5951ms - Started 325 of 575 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 393 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Tried few times but it gives the same errors. This is the error that I am getting when I opened standalone.batch file

Comment: I'm no expert at this at all, but `Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9990` looks like there is already a process running on that port... you don't have it configured as a service do you?

Comment: I tried looking for the port in resource monitor but no service is using that port @Isaac

Comment: Something is using that port as @Isaac said.  But it isn't another instance of Wildfly because port 8080 and 8443 were ok.  Is this a fresh Wildfly install?

Comment: no. This is the second one. I deleted first one by mistake. How can I stop that service now? @stdunbar

Answer (score 0):

For Windows operating system:

```
netstat  -ano  |  findstr  9990
```

This command will list the process info at the specified port number which is something like this.

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:9990         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4108
```

At the end you will process id now take this id and kill the process as below.

```
taskkill  /F  /PID  4108
```

If you encounter `Access is denied` problem then run the comandline as administrator and kill the process id that you found.